# Opening Additional Mailboxes using Java Mail API

Tags: jakarta-mail

Additional mailboxes can be configured to a user using MS Outlook Client. I presume a shared mail group can also be added this way.

http://www.vlerick.com/helpdesk/our_services/faq/software_solution/microsoft/outlook/faq_additional_mailbox.html

I am trying to develop a java program to read emails using java mail api. I am currently trying to connect and read using POP3 protocol. Is there any way to read mails from other shared mail boxes configured for a user using java mail api?

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Do you want to open multiple users' Inboxes via POP, or do you want to open several shared folders that aren't Inboxes?

Comment: I want to open several shared folders that have inboxes of their own. When I view these folders using ms outlook client each of these folders are called mailbox with a different name. Each of these mailboxes are configured pertaining to a group mail id. any mails to the group mail ids goes into the 'Inbox' folder of approropriate mailbox. My Java program goes and directly picks mails from 'Inbox' of default mail box. Is there anyway using java mail api to read mails in inbox of other mailboxes even if it means using imap api?